# Popup images show up with a scrollbar in magnific-popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I am using magnific-popup to show images of a gallery with an iframe.
Popup works but images show up with a scrollbar.

I have tried adding a class setting width in 100% but did not work.

```
<script id="rendered-js">
    $('.modal').magnificPopup({
        type: 'iframe',


        gallery: {
            enabled: true, 

            preload: [0, 1], 

            navigateByImgClick: true,

            arrowMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-arrow mfp-arrow-%dir%"></button>', // markup of an arrow button

            tPrev: 'Previous (Left arrow key)', 
            tNext: 'Next (Right arrow key)', 
            tCounter: '<span class="mfp-counter">%curr% of %total%</span>' 
        },

        iframe: {
            markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">' +
                '<div class="mfp-close"></div>' +
                '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' +
                '<div class="mfp-title">Some caption</div>' +
                '</div>'

        },

        callbacks: {
            markupParse: function (template, values, item) {
                values.title = item.el.attr('title');
            }
        }
    });
    //# sourceURL=pen.js
</script>`
```

There are no error messages, just the scroll bar that shows up with each image.

Answer (score 0):

To hide this vertical scrollbar (and the horizontal scrollbar if that appears too), you need to use the CSS `overflow` property, with a value of `hidden`.

```
.modal {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding the modal class to the iframe markup and also to the figure tags but did not work. `iframe: {
                markup: 
                    '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">' +
                    '<div class="mfp-close"></div>' +
                    '<iframe class="mfp-iframe modal" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' +
                    '<div class="mfp-title">Some caption</div>' +
                    '</div>'

            },`. Also tried adding overflow-y: 'hidden', in the pop-up initializer: `